# How to override dojo's domReady

Tags: dojo

I want to override dijit._CssStateMixin's domReady() method.
Is there any way to override that instead of changing the listener mechanism in Dojo.

I tried overriding _cssMouseEvent() method in simple javascript, but it still does invoke dijit's _cssMouseEvent() from domReady().

I have tried following approach:

```
 dojoConfig = {
        map: {
            'dijit/_CssStateMixin': {
                    'dojo/domReady': 'app/noop'
            }
    }
};
```

I have added 'app' folder and then 'noop.js' inside that.
noop.js has nothing in it:

```
    define([], function () {
    return function () {};
});
```

Even after this I can see that dijit.js's _CssStateMaxin domReady() getting called from listener.apply (code snippet pasted below)

```
var addStopImmediate = function(listener){
        return function(event){
            if(!event.immediatelyStopped){// check to make sure it hasn't been stopped immediately
                event.stopImmediatePropagation = stopImmediatePropagation;
                return listener.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason _why_ you want to override that?  It seems like a pretty unorthodox request.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Ken, actually the problem is by using dijit tree I am seeing lag while scrolling in tree. I figured out root cause that _cssMouseEvent() is the one which is causing lag issue as it tries to add many watch callbacks on each tree node. I don't want that to happen. And the next issue is though I was able to override _cssMouseEvent method, dojo does invoke its own method from domReady(). So I need to override domReady itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ultimate goal is to prevent the `domReady` callback in `dijit/_CssStateMixin` from running, your simplest bet is likely to re-map `dojo/domReady` to a different module that doesn't call the callback at all, when loaded via `dijit/_CssStateMixin`.

**NOTE:** Stripping out these handlers might have adverse visual effects on Dijit widgets which inherit `_CssStateMixin`, since it may hinder the application of Dijit CSS classes related to hover and focus.  But if your concern is that `_CssStateMixin` is hampering performance, it may at least be worth a try to confirm or deny your suspicion.

First we have to create a simple module that returns a function that does nothing, which we will later substitute for `dojo/domReady` when loaded by `dijit/_CssStateMixin`, so that it can still call `domReady` but it won't execute the callback it passes.

For simplicity's sake I'll assume you already have a custom package that you can easily add a module to; for this example I'll assume it's called `app`.  Let's create `app/noop`:

```
define([], function () {
    return function () {};
});
```

Now let's configure the loader to map `app/noop` in place of `dojo/domReady` specifically when loaded by `dijit/_CssStateMixin`:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    ...,
    map: {
            'dijit/_CssStateMixin': {
                    'dojo/domReady': 'app/noop'
            }
    },
    ...
};
```

Now the offending `domReady` callback should no longer be run.

If you're curious about `map`, you can read more about it in this [SitePen FAQ](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/07/03/dojo-faq-what-is-the-map-config-option/).

Comment: Ken, I have tried following approach:
1. Defined my own module: 
define(["dojo/dom"], function(dom) {
   return { 
      test: function() { 
        alert('inside my module') 
       } 
    }; 
}); 

2.Later in the dojoConfig I have mapped the domReady with this function as: 

dojoConfig = { 
            map : { 
                   'dijit/_CssStateMixin': { 
                                    'dojo/domReady': 'app/myModule/test' 
                                                        } 
                } 
      }; 

After doing as well I can see that the domReady is not getting overridden.

Comment: Can you post a gist or update your original question with the code you have that is responsible for configuring and loading Dojo?  I tested my approach before I wrote my answer and it is operating as expected for me.

Comment: I have updated the question with the approach that I've tried.

Comment: Where is your dojo.js script tag relative to your dojoConfig?  Do you have any other dojoConfig elsewhere?

Comment: dojo.js is below the dojoConfig declaration. Means I could see the dojoConfig getting loaded before dojo js is loaded.And no other dojoConfig is present elsewhere apart from the defined one.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what to say.  https://gist.github.com/kfranqueiro/09ddadee144cdaeb7ca2 is literally my entire test case and it's clearly executing my no-op function instead.

Comment: Ken, thanks for ur help! I couldn't achieve the domReady overriding, but I could override layoutChildren() of utils js with ur approach.