# Should most Dojo modules require dojo/domReady?

Tags: javascript, dojo, jasmine

I'm starting to unit test some of my Dojo modules, and dojo/domReady! is causing trouble.  (Specifically, any time I require a module that has dojo/domReady! somewhere in its sub-tree of requirements, Jasmine silently pretends the test doesn't exist.)  I've been requiring it in every module that touches the DOM because I didn't think it could possibly do any harm.  Now I'm wondering if I actually *need* to call it everywhere or if it's really only necessary at the top level.

In my case, I'm writing a widget for Esri's Web AppBuilder.  It's got a single entry point called Widget.js.  If I require dojo/domReady! in Widget.js, can I safely omit it in all my other modules?  Would a better solution be to override domReady in unit tests like what's talked about in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27956472/1238206)?

Comment: I guess I spoke too soon about domReady being the problem.  Apparently the ! is the culprit.  My tests aren't run any time I use a plugin (like 'dojo/text!something.html').  Overriding domReady.js doesn't help.  I think it might be related to this: https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18123  It looks like I might be out of luck for now, unless if the answer to my actual question is "yes".

Comment: One more update - I've found that if I use [StubModule](https://github.com/agrc/StubModule) to pull in the module I'm testing, everything magically works.  I can't explain it, but I can say that I'm head over heels in love with StubModule!  I'm happy that I have a workaround to my current problem, but if anyone has an answer to my initial question, I'm still very interested in hearing it.

Comment: It sounds like the problem you are running into is that you are using a test system that doesn’t understand AMD modules and has poor support for asynchronous operations, so it is not able to wait for the DOM ready loader plugin (or ANY loader plugin) to finish resolving before starting your tests. Maybe you should revisit using Intern instead, which does support this out of the box, instead of using a less capable test system and getting into more trouble :)

Comment: @CSnover - Well you've clearly got a preference.  It almost seems like you're the author of Intern or something!  ;)  But seriously, I tried **very** hard to get Intern up and running.  Unfortunately I just couldn't get it to work with my desired cocktail of JS libraries.  I jumped back and forth between Intern and Jasmine for like two weeks before finally getting Jasmine to function properly.

Comment: Yes, I am biased, but that’s because I researched *every* testing library before I wrote it, and issues like these are why it was created in the first place: other test systems simply don’t handle modularity or asynchronicity correctly. I only see you ever asked one question about Intern and it was answered a few hours later so I’m confused why you don’t ask for help earlier to get things up and running if you have been trying for two weeks! :)

Comment: SO is usually a last resort for me, and when I do ask a question, I tend to be wordy enough that I think of something else to try while I'm in the middle of typing the question.  Then I just scrap the question and keep experimenting.  I think I did that two or three times while working on Intern!  This question was short enough that I had time to submit it before going on and adding those two comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dojo/domReady!` is a plugin to delay loading a module until DOM is loaded. `domReady!` plugin binds itself to browser's dom-ready event, which gets fired as soon as DOM is ready. However, this does not mean that all of your widgets have been parsed... You can add `dojo/ready` in your module's dependencies and enclose your module code inside `ready(function(){ // your code });` within your module, if you need to run your code after all widgets have been parsed.

Re: your question about whether you need to use `dojo/domReady!` once for all widgets: you would typically use `ready()` once at the root of your bootstrapping module, and all other dependencies are loaded and parsed thereafter. For test code, you would probably use `ready()` to ensure all of the widgets are parsed.

As for distinction between `dojo/domReady` vs `dojo/domReady!`, Dojo loader will treat the latter as a plugin, and string after `!` is taken as argument for plugins. In domReady case, plugin results in  delaying module's loading until DOM is ready.. If you do not include the `!` then the loader will load domReady as a utility and won't treat it like a plugin. For more on plugins, look at [here](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd#plugins)...

+1 for your follow-up comments above!

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you're suggesting that I use `domReady!` at the entry point and `ready()` everywhere else?  I'm surprised because that seems to go against the dojo/ready documentation (https://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.10/dojo/ready.html), which says, "In most cases, the domReady plug-in should suffice and this method should not be needed."

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting to use them both at the same time. One or the other, `ready` is more appropriate if you need to wait until all other widgets are parsed.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  I guess I might be able to get away with `ready()` then, since the DOM will have been created by the framework and my widget just adds to it.  Thanks!

Comment: `dojo/ready` is *heavily discouraged* in modern applications.  Prior to Dojo 1.7 (which adopted AMD), it was the only way to wait for modules and the document to load. In 1.7+, it is redundant of `dojo/domReady!` plus `require` callbacks. Regarding parser, you don't need `dojo/ready` either if you run the parser yourself (rather than rely on `parseOnLoad`). Either load all modules the parser needs prior to parsing, or wait for the promise returned by `parser.parse` to resolve before trying to interact with declaratively-created widgets.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info @KenFranqueiro.  Now I'm confused again though!  Does `parse` do more than process things that have been specified with the declarative syntax?  I tend to use the programmatic interface more, although I do have a few declarative things sprinkled in.  Given that the DOM itself is created by a framework that's out of my control, is the best practice to omit `dojo/domReady!`, call `parser.parse`, and let the loader handle resolving all the other modules I've defined?

Comment: Parse does exactly what you described, but in 1.8+, the parser is also able to automatically require modules that haven't yet been loaded, which can cause the `parse` call to resolve asynchronously, which is why I brought up its promise.  If all of the modules referenced via `data-dojo-type` are already loaded when `parser.parse` is called, it will execute synchronously. Regarding `dojo/domReady!`, unless you are either loading Dojo and your modules at the bottom of the `body` or even after the initial document load, you should still include `dojo/domReady!` in your top-level `require`.